# Using Rules to calculate end date based on start date

Tags: 7, rules, datetime

I have a reservation content type with field_start_date that the user sets for staying. Users can update this node at any time. I want to be able to:
Calculate the field_end_date based on the proposed field_start_date + 7 days and save it in read-only field_end_date

- I checked the computed field type, but it either does calculation only once at creation time and stores the value in the database or it does calculation at seeing node and therefore can not be used in views.
- I also tried Math Expression but I couldn't get it to work.
  My best bet is now to have two rules: one does the calculate field_end_date when a node gets created and the next one when a node gets updated.
  Any help is appreciated, thanks,